# (simple) problem with changing type and key error in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**DataFrame**

| x | y | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 7 |
| 1 | 0 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |

```
def my_function(x,y):
    print(df["num"][(df["x"] == x) & (df["y"] == y + 1)])

x = my_function(1,1)
print(x)
print(type(x))

Out:
3    10
Name: num, dtype: int64
None
<class 'NoneType'>
```

I don't know why its becoming NoneType instead of pandas.series
and how can i get "num" value here ("10")

x[0] gives key error :<

Comment: Updated the answer per your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be returning the value from the function like below code.

```py
def my_function(x,y):
    print(df["num"][(df["x"] == x) & (df["y"] == y + 1)])
    return df["num"][(df["x"] == x) & (df["y"] == y + 1)]

x = my_function(1,1)
print(x)
print(type(x))

print(x.index.values)
print(x[3])

# Output below
3    10
Name: num, dtype: int64
3    10
Name: num, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
[3]
10
```

The `series` which the function is returning, has `index value - 3` only hence the key error when you pass `0`. pass `3` instead like in above code it will work